# Limit number of connections per IP on Netty

Tags: java, netty

I've been searching for a while a way to limit the connections per IP on Netty using its IPFilter class. However, there is no JavaDoc explanation to do that kind of limitations.

The only way i've found is using the 'ConnectionPerIPLimitUpStreamHandler' released on jboss two years ago, but Norman Maurer said that it was no longer needed cuz this feature has been added to the IPFilter class.

So, in resume, I need an explanation on how we could limit connections per IP address on Netty using its IPFilter class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me like you can take the source to `OneIpFilterHandler` and

1) change the concurrent map so the values are `Integer` to hold the count.
2) change the place where it checks the IP of a new connection to allow if the count is below the threshhold.
3) change that same place to increment the count when you allow
4) change the place where it releases an IP address to reduce the count and remove the map entry if its zero.

Think about concurrent issues through all this.

I know this is vague. But its an idea. It might help you.

Comment: Yes, i've thought adding my own filter to the pipeline would be the only way to do that, however i'm looking for a 'precompiled-in-netty' way and i've readed a comment of Norman Maurer which said it was included on the IPFilter class.

I hope he can get onto this question and resolve it.