# Netty4: How can i limit the number of connections?

Tags: java, netty

We are using a RaspPi as Server-Platform to export some data from it. Thus a RaspPi has limited resources we want to limit the number of connections to eg. 16.
How can we do that using Netty 4?

We didn't found a out of the box solution on github for netty 4 only for netty 3 (see:[Limit number of connections per IP on Netty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16368650/limit-number-of-connections-per-ip-on-netty)).

Is it okay to extend `ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter` and simply count the number of active connections and if the max. is reached call close() on every new connection like this:

```
private final AtomicInteger activeConnections = new AtomicInteger();

@Override
public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
    if (activeConnections.get()<16)
        activeConnections.incrementAndGet();
    else
    ctx.close();
}

@Override
public void channelInactive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    activeConnections.decrementAndGet();
}
```